# Keys of Spring beans as Map<String,Foo>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

trying to instantiate a Map in Spring I found an odd (to me) behaviour. 
I am using the following piece of XML to create the Map:

```
<bean id="fooBean" class="it.arch.fe.util.Foo">
    <property name="prop1" value="val1"></property>
    <property name="prop2" value="val2"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="barBean" class="it.arch.fe.util.Foo">
    <property name="prop1" value="val3"></property>
    <property name="prop2" value="val4"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="mapOfFoos" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetMapClass">
        <value>java.util.HashMap</value>
    </property>
    <property name="sourceMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="foo" value-ref="fooBean" />
            <entry key="bar" value-ref="barBean" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I manage to instantiate and Autowire this Map in my code, but I am having an issue with the keys:

I wanted a map with keys "foo" and "bar", but they appear to be "fooBean" and "barBean".

Is this supposed to happen? 
Is there a way to use the "key" properties as keys, as it would seem the obvious behaviour?

(I don't want to change the names of the beans to foo and bar, because I already declared two beans with these names and the logic I would like to follow needs the keys to be "foo" and "bar")

EDIT: Starting from Trever Shick's answer I found a way to resolve the practical problem, but I'm still trying to understand why this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use a map, don't use a MapFactoryBean for your mapOfFoos

`<beans xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">`

```
<util:map id="mapOfFoos">
    <entry key="foo" value-ref="fooBean" />
    <entry key="bar" value-ref="barBean" />
</util:map>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am trying to make your snippet work, but the "map" tag seems not to support the "id" key. Am I supposed to put the whole <map>..</map> inside a "bean" tag?

Comment: Ok, I researched a bit more and it seems I can't just instantiate a map by itself. It has to be inside a MapFactoryBean or as a property inside another bean. Are you suggesting the latter?

Comment: util:map should allow the use of an id.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/xsd-config.html

Comment: Thanks for the input, now I tried also with util:maps, but the library behind it must be doing the same operations as the MapFactoryBean, since the keys I end up with are the same (fooBean and barBean)

Comment: Here : https://github.com/trevershick/so1


    Oct 30, 2013 4:51:50 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
    INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@42d72882: defining beans [fooBean,barBean,mapOfFoos]; root of factory hierarchy
    foo=>com.trevershick.github.proof.so1.FooBean@6d90d6c5
    bar=>com.trevershick.github.proof.so1.BarBean@400457b5

Comment: Wow, you're really committed to this! Thanks a lot!

I ran your code and the keys were "foo" and "bar", as expected, but when I make the same checks on my beans(instantiated with util:map), the keys turn out to be "fooBean" and "barBean".

For now I'm going to stick to my (not pretty) workaround, because this behaviour must be caused by some setting of the architecture I'm in..I gotta look around some more,  Thank you a lot for the time you spent helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Since I found I can't instantiate a Map by itself as a bean without a MapFactoryBean or as a property inside another bean, I resolved in another way:

I made another class, InnerFoo with attributes prop1 and prop2, where I put the properties I had in the previous Foo, so now my `Map<String,InnerFoo>` is the only attribute of Foo, this is my xml snippet:

```
<bean id="fooBean" class="it.arch.fe.util.InnerFoo">
    <property name="prop1" value="val1"></property>
    <property name="prop2" value="val2"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="barBean" class="it.arch.fe.util.InnerFoo">
    <property name="prop1" value="val3"></property>
    <property name="prop2" value="val4"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="mapOfFoos" class="it.arch.fe.util.Foo">
    <property name="mapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="foo" value-ref="fooBean" />
            <entry key="bar" value-ref="barBean" />
        </map>
    </property>     
</bean>
```